# Vue component not updating after parent state change

Tags: vue.js

I have Vue component which receives json data from props, after this render child components using `v-for` and pass this data as prop. Everything works fine until i try to remove one item from this list, when i remove it, it removes element incorrectly. In vue devtools i see that parent receives data correctly but not renders it properly. can anyone help me?
here is my code: https://gist.github.com/giokaxo/3d291b9b7b8ef97f81dc83799c430302

Answer (score 1):

Use "key" attribute when rendering elements using v-for, for example:

```
<p v-for="(product, index) in order.products" :key="i">..</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant documentation is [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for):

> You can directly use `v-for` on a custom component, like any normal
> element:

> ```
> <my-component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"></my-component>
> ```

> > **In 2.2.0+, when using `v-for` with a component, a `key` is now required.**

> However, this won’t automatically
> pass any data to the component, because components have isolated
> scopes of their own. In order to pass the iterated data into the
> component, we should also use props:

```
   <my-component
     v-for="(item, index) in items"
     v-bind:item="item"
     v-bind:index="index"  
     v-bind:key="item.id">
   </my-component>
```

> The reason for not automatically injecting item into the component is because that makes the component
> tightly coupled to how `v-for` works. Being explicit about where its
> data comes from makes the component reusable in other situations.

And [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key):

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, it by
> default uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data
> items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the
> order of the items, Vue will simply patch each element in-place and
> make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular
> index.

...

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus
> reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key
> attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id
> of each item.